# Archiva fails to publish using gradle

Tags: gradle, archiva

My continuous integration thats running on Bamboo worked fine with Archiva. Suddenly I'm getting the following error when publishing

> error 03-Feb-2015 04:57:23 Caused by: java.net.SocketException:
>   Unexpected end of file from server error 03-Feb-2015 04:57:23 at
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.LightweightHttpWagon.finishPutTransfer(LightweightHttpWagon.java:185)
>   error 03-Feb-2015 04:57:23 ... 73 more

Any idea on whats happening ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was due to a disk corruption on the Bamboo Server